# how to give pointers elements without malloc oder calloc

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, malloc

I want to know if you can Allocate memory without using malloc or calloc, on a char pointer.

as an example:

```
char *p;
```

and now i want to do this

```
*(p+1) = 'd'
printf("%c", *(p+1));
```

and the output is 'd'. i want this to work without malloc or calloc

Comment: If you explain why you want this, you may get better answers.

Comment: i just want to understand how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the pointer with the reference to the object of a suitable type and size.

`malloc` returns the reference to the suitable block of memory.

You can also assign the statically (or automatically if used in the block context) allocated object.

```
char data[2];
char *p;
 /* ... */

p = data;
*(p+1) = 'd'
printf("%c", *(p+1));
```

So basically the pointer has to reference the valid object.

Comment: _"`malloc` returns the reference..."_, actually `malloc` returns a _pointer_.

Comment: @Jabberwocky explain the difference if you know any and it was so important to write this comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky The C++ language is the only case I know that makes a distinction. But the term reference/pass by reference predates C++ by a decade or two. It's a generic computer science term, the opposite of pass by value.

Comment: The correct word is _pointer_. At least I never have seen the word "reference" in any C documentation. OTOH in C++ there is a big difference between "pointer" and "reference".

Comment: @Lundin that's true, but still in C there is no pass by reference at all. IMHO a pointer should just be called a pointer.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sure there is. In case of `void foo (int* p)` the pointer `p` is passed by value and the contents pointed-at by `p` are passed by reference. For the formal definition see C17 6.2.5/20: "A _pointer type_ may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the _referenced type_. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference
to an entity of the referenced type."

Comment: @Jabberwocky The function is returning a value of a 'pointer type' not the pointer.  From the C standard *`A pointer type derived from
the referenced type T is sometimes called ‘‘pointer to T ’’`*

Answer (score 0):

C is just human readable assembly, every thing is to be done by the programmer. No fancy garbage collector is a fact but still it has a cutting edge (Rather to say a blunt knife and a file given to you).

Pointer sanitation is a term which you need to be aware of. As soon as you make a pointer variable, you need to assign it some valid memory address. If it is not possible at that time assign it to be NULL.

```
char * p; // pointing to random location due to grabage value.
*(p+1) = 'd'; // you are overwiting there
printf("%c", *(p+1)); // printing single character
```

what should be done is.

```
char *p = NULL;
*(p+1) = 'd'; // this will pop error which you can see in gdb
...
...
```